# Change or remove artist pictures in iTunes 12

Tags: itunes, windows

*First, to make it perfectly clear, this is about **Artist** artwork, not Album artwork, since most of the questions I could find related to Artist artwork had answers referring to album or genre artwork instead.*

In iTunes 12 on Windows 10, I don't always like or want the artwork iTunes chooses for a given artist. Sometimes (perhaps only for music not bought from iTunes, but I haven't done a rigorous experiment) I can trick it by changing the name of the artist (e.g. adding a space or extra letters after the artist name). But for other artists, even if I completely change the artist and album artist, it still "knows" which artist it is and uses their artwork.

I've seen suggestions for fixing this in previous versions of iTunes that involved things like changing song ratings, etc., and I even tried using Mp3tag to strip out iTunes-related tags on a song purchased from iTunes, but nothing has worked.

Acceptable solutions would get iTunes to do one of the following:

- Display no artwork for a particular artist.
- Display artwork for one of the artist's albums as the artist artwork.
- Display no artwork for any artists.
- Use artwork I specify for a particular artist.

Comment: Are you okay with a third party software?

Comment: @William Yes, third party software for altering the song files is fine.

Comment: @William did you have a third party suggestion in mind?

Comment: hmm well I hadn't fully read the question but something like Mp3tag is kinda what I had in mind. You could import the song into something like Garageband and reexport that should let you set custom tags and clear out the artwork but I'm just guessing.  I'm sorry you haven't gotten more interest in this question.

Comment: @William Thanks for the followup. It's also possible I didn't know how to do it correctly in Mp3tag--the interface seemed less than intuitive in terms of making sure I cleared everything. Unfortunately I don't have a mac to be able to try Garageband.

Comment: did you ever find the answer? 2018 and I still hate the default microphone.